# Ubuntu 16.04 Changes Installed Emacs Version

Tags: package-management, software-center, emacs

I used [this guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/09/install-gnu-emacs-25-1-in-ubuntu-16-04/) to build emacs 25.1 on 16.04 and accomplished it without a problem.

Before installing, I did not have `emacs` installed. A part of the building process, however, is to `sudo apt build-dep emacs24` to build the necessary dependencies for emacs. That said, once I am done, I have emacs 25.1 installed without a problem (including the proper `emacs` command within term and launcher in Unity's dash).

However, after a day or two, Ubuntu seems to automatically install emacs24 from the Ubuntu repositories/software center, which then overrides my custom install/build of emacs25. This has now happened twice and I **think** it occurs whenever I do a system update via term. I will be given a message along the lines of "there is a newer version of an installed package" and `sudo apt list --upgradeable` will list emacs, despite emacs25.1 being obviously newer than the version in Ubuntu's repositories.

The directory where I built emacs25.1 still has the executable (and all other files) which I can call manually, but this is not ideal. Further, I luckily have a deb file built that allows me to reinstall emacs25.1 after I uninstall emacs24 via Ubuntu's software center, but I would like to fix this behavior if possible. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the emacs package on hold.
If you use APT:

Hold a package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>
```

Remove the hold:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package-name>
```